# How to write code in multiple projects in one solution at once? [Visual Studio/Xamarin]

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, msbuild

I have a solution where I have multiple projects. Right now I have 3 different .sln-files that I have connected to their own .csproj and when I want to work with one of the apps I just launch that particular .sln-file and it works very well. The only problem I have now is that these 3 projects share tons of code so I look to create a solution where I can write code in one of the projects where the code would also get written in the other projects. They share the same files, filenames etc. The only difference is essentially the images, icons etc. When I did some quick research I came across this quote:

”A project can be referenced by multiple solutions. Put your library or core code into one project, then reference that project in both solutions.”

I guess some additional references/adjustments has to be made in each of the .csproj-files and .stl-files?

What i was thinking in my head is that when new code is written then that file should overwrite the same file from the other projects with the updated code. How this solution would be made is something i however do not know.

Any code examples, tips, tricks, guidance is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to write code in multiple projects in one solution at once? [Visual Studio/Xamarin]

You can create a project to include the shared tons of code, then add this project to other solutions. Then when new code is written then that file should overwrite the same file from the other projects with the updated code.

To accomplish this, please check following test sample for detail:

1. Create a project with shared code, for example, `ShareProject` with following code:

   ```
   public void test()
   {
       System.Console.Write("This is only for Test update1");
   }
   ```
2. Create a solution1, `Add`->`existing project`..., select the `ShareProject`.
3. Create a solution2, `Add`->`existing project`..., select the `ShareProject`.
4. Update code in the `shareProject`.

[image]

With this setting, when new code is written then that file should overwrite the same file from the other projects with the updated code.